# fills a given polygon with a few types of given primitives

Tags: co.combinatorics, gt.geometric-topology

Given one large 2D polygon, and K types of small polygons (the primitives). For each type of small polygon, it can be rotated, and has an infinite number of pieces. For such a Jigsaw puzzle
game, is there an optimal/suboptimal solution for calculating the maximum area within the large polygon that can be filled using small polygons, and the corresponding procedure for reaching it?

Comment: It's not even known how best to pack copies of one size square into a bigger square. I doubt there's much can be said about a problem as general as what's being asked here. You might enjoy having a look at https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/index.html

Comment: The problem of filling the entire polygon is surely NP-complete. For suboptimal solutions you should ask here: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

As Sam Nead suggested:

> Demaine, Erik D., and Martin L. Demaine. "Jigsaw puzzles, edge matching, and polyomino packing: Connections and complexity." *Graphs and Combinatorics* 23, no. 1 (2007): 195-208.

"We show that jigsaw puzzles, edge-matching puzzles, and polyomino packing puzzles are all NP-complete."

[image: Fig7]

For approximation algorithms, look at the literature on
[textile layout](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Eeppstein/gina/textile.html).